# Error : Class 'Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException' not found

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, jwt

I am creating rest api using codeigniter, [Rest Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver), and [firebase php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) . following is my code to create jwt token.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require_once APPPATH . '/libraries/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class Welcome extends REST_Controller 
{
    public function __construct($config = 'rest') 
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->load->model("Users_model");
    }
    public function login_post() 
    {
        $username = $this->post('username');
        $password = $this->post('password');
        $invalidLogin = ['invalid' => $username];
        if(!$username || !$password){
            $this->response($invalidLogin, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        $id = $this->Users_model->checkLogin($username,$password);
        if($id) {
            $token['id'] = $id;
            $token['username'] = $username;
            $date = new DateTime();
            $token['iat'] = $date->getTimestamp();
            $token['exp'] = $date->getTimestamp() + 60*60*5;
            $output['id_token'] = JWT::encode($token, $this->config->item('jwt_secret_key'));
            $this->set_response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        } else {
            $this->set_response($invalidLogin, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    /******** This is target test function having error **********/ 
    public function test_post()
    {
        $token = $this->input->get_request_header('Authorization');
        try{
            $payload = JWT::decode($token, $this->config->item('jwt_secret_key'),array('HS256'));
            $this->response($payload, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $response = array("message" => $ex->getMessage());
            $this->response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } 
    }
}
```

i have following files in my libraries folder

1. BeforeValidException.php
2. ExpiredException.php
3. Format.php
4. JWT.php
5. REST_Controller.php
6. SignatureInvalidException.php

when i tested with postman with false token (altering string in signature) the error is given that

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> ```
> Type: Error
> Message: Class 'Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException' not found
> Filename: .../application/libraries/JWT.php</p>
> Line Number: 113
> ```

following code is there on Jwt.php

```
    // Check the signature
    if (!static::verify("$headb64.$bodyb64", $sig, $key, $header->alg)) {
        throw new SignatureInvalidException('Signature verification failed');  // This is line 113
    }
```

but i have this file in my libraries folder.
 any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you put JWT file here

Comment: i have given a link to respective repo. i'll update q and post the code from that file

Comment: i think you have to require_once signature before JWT.php

Comment: @Jinesh this solved my issue, Thanks!!!

Comment: I recommend this library to work with firebase from php, it´s the best: [link](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html)

Comment: if it is helpful can you accept my answer @ The Megamind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to `require_once` signature before `JWT.php`

file will be something like this in codeigniter libraries.

```
class SignatureInvalidException extends \UnexpectedValueException
{
}
```